# Help with forms and nonces

Tags: forms, nonce

I am trying to create a nonce to use with a (public-facing) form.

Below is my code:

```
function my_form() {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $output_form = false;

        if (wp_verify_nonce($_POST['added'], 'add-item') )
        {
        //validate
        echo 'form submitted with nonce correctly';
        }

    } else {
       $output_form = true;
    }
    if ($output_form) {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('add-item','added'); ?>
            <label>Title:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/><br/>
            <label>Description:</label><br />
            <textarea name="description" rows="3" cols="10"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    <?php
    }   

}

add_shortcode('PODS FORM', my_form);
```

I can see my form on my page, but when I submit (and fill it our correctly) instead of seeing my 'correct' message I am only seeing blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the **value of the nonce field** as first argument to [wp_verify_nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce). So, you need to modify the nonce verification part in your code.

Also you were using form fields names that conflicts with internal wordpress query vars, you should prefix them with something unique so they do not conflict with wordpress. See following example:

```
function my_form() {
    if (isset($_POST['pf_submit'])) { 

    $name = $_POST['pf_name'];
    $description = $_POST['pf_description'];
    $output_form = false;

        if (isset( $_POST['pf_added'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['pf_added'], 'add-item') )
        {
        //validate
        echo 'form submitted with nonce correctly';
        }

    } else {
       $output_form = true;
       $name = "";
       $description = "";
    }
    if ($output_form) {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('add-item','pf_added'); ?>
            <label>Title:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="pf_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/><br/>
            <label>Description:</label><br />
            <textarea name="pf_description" rows="3" cols="10"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="pf_submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    <?php
    }   

}

add_shortcode('PODS FORM', my_form);
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I added your code but I am still getting a "Page not found" error (changes to the code made above)

Comment: still getting Page not found? You said in your question you are seeing the blank page. Blank page and page not found are two different issues. Kindly confirm if you are seeing the blank page or page not found. I just looked at the other parts of your code and they look buggy too. Give me few minutes and I will get back to you.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the complete fixed code.

Comment: Actually, this works great! The renaming helped!

Comment: Just wondering...do I have to pass a difference nonce each time?

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything with nonces. The wp_nonce_field and wp_verify_nonce will take care of generating and verifying unique nonce everytime.

Comment: You can just check if the nonce validates, if so handle the data as you need, if the nonce checks it's implied that the `$_POST['pf_submit']` is set.